# How do i get the coordinates of a view during animation android

Tags: java, android, animation

these are just the methods i can override during animationListener.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

```
Animation animation

animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.device_box);

animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
        @Overridepublic void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}});
```

I think adding a thread in onAnimationStart and stop it on onAnimationEnd and getting the coordinates with a loop inside the thread, this may work.
But i think that i could get some problems with buttons because, when animating them in this way, only the background moves, not button area itself

In this case, i have to investigate more with buttons

What do you think about this, is there another way to achieve what i want?
Is this the better way to do it ?

Comment: I think the problem is how you define your animation. Please show the code of this: Animation animation = new ???

Answer (score 0):

I researched, and what I got is this, not X and Y but can handle the data as get what has been animated as time.

```
                 ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(box_image, "translationX", 0 , cant);

                  anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator arg0) {

                                  double f = Math.round(arg0.getAnimatedFraction()*1000.0)/1000.0;
                                    Log.d("datos", ""+f);
                                }
                            });
                  anim.setDuration(1000);
                  anim.start();
```